# Expandability in Mobile app Burger menus

Tags: gui-design, ux-field, material-design, guidelines, human-interface-guideline

Is it correct to use expandable items (Nested Menus) in burger menus in mobile apps?

Something like this

[image]

Comment: could you show some mockups?

Comment: @Mayo

something like this: 

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/186547609537502074/

Comment: @MasoodFarsaei add the image to your original question with a little more context and detail and you will get some nice answers probably.

Comment: This is really common in eCommerce as it helps IA of deep lists. You don't want a burger menu forcing a user to scroll down the page any more the absolutely necessary

Answer (score 1):

I have just completed an app that utilized just this sort of menu. It was for a tablet (1024) but I expect the findings would be the same for small mobile devices.

We asked users to find "X". They went to the hamburger icon and had zero issue in navigating to a submenu. Not one subject raised an eyebrow.

Our test subjects ranged from 20 something to 60 something. This was a business app for employees so they were motivated to understand what they were using. (This may be an important difference when compared to the general population.)

It caused so little issue that we stopped directly testing for this and then asked (new) people to do a task which required them to find the hamburger icon, drill down and go to the section to do the task. Again, there wasn't a problem with the nested menu.

---

As a side note my one quibble with your design would be to make the nested portion a little more pronounced. Perhaps indenting the nested portion a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a look at [NNG guidelines](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/hamburger-menus/) for web and mobile design, their studies show that regarding hamburger menus, in summary:

> Discoverability is cut almost in half by hiding a website’s main navigation. Also, task time is longer and perceived task difficulty increases.

Since your question is about nested menus within a Hamburger menu, we could assume that the nested menus hides navigation beneath another level. This means that discoverability and, in turn, task length will be increased even further.

**However,** in many cases such menus are difficult to avoid with the amount of features and functionality some apps have. As this is often the case you should bring all the key features and functions to the front of the interface.

You can determine what key features are most important with methods like card sorting and prioritization.